# levenshtein formula in search

Tags: php, laravel, search, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to use Levinstein's formula in the search. My task is that if someone writes **botmen** on the word, they find the closest options. In my case, first should be **batman** and then **superman** and **x-man**. But it gives me this result instead. Can anyone help me with the problem?

My tags data

```
$tags = [
            [
                'title' => 'Superman',
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Batman',
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'X-man',
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Unbelievable',
            ],     [
                'title' => 'Ted Lasso',
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Loki',
            ],     [
                'title' => 'Dopesick',
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Bosch',
            ],     [
                'title' => 'The Professional',
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Incendies',
            ],
        ];
```

my code

```
        $searchString = 'botmen'; 
        $threshold = 3; 

        $results = DB::table('tags')
            ->select('title','id', DB::raw("levenshtein_ratio('$searchString', title) as ratio"))
            ->whereRaw("levenshtein_ratio('$searchString', title) <= $threshold")
            ->orderBy('ratio', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

what result i get

```
[
    {
        "title": "The Professional",
        "id": 9,
        "ratio": -133
    },
    {
        "title": "Unbelievable",
        "id": 4,
        "ratio": -67
    },
    {
        "title": "Ted Lasso",
        "id": 5,
        "ratio": -50
    },
    {
        "title": "Incendies",
        "id": 10,
        "ratio": -33
    },
    {
        "title": "Loki",
        "id": 6,
        "ratio": -25
    },
    {
        "title": "Dopesick",
        "id": 7,
        "ratio": -17
    },
    {
        "title": "Superman",
        "id": 1,
        "ratio": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: There might be an issue with your usage of the `levenshtein_ratio` function. The function is returning negative values, which should not happen with